# Cassandra cql: select N “most recent” rows in ascending order

Tags: cassandra, cql

I understand that the best way to fetch the most recent rows in Cassandra is to create my table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data1(
               asset_id int
               date timestamp,
               value decimal,
               PRIMARY KEY ((asset_id), date)
            ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date desc);
```

Then select 1000 recent data items via:

```
select * from data1 where asset_id = 8 limit 1000;
```

The client requires the data in ascending order.
Server side is python.
Is there a way to reverse the results in CQL and not in code (i.e. python)?

Comment: If you can provide the date of nth row, then you can order asc in cql

Comment: Just as a side note, interesting discussion on this topic here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4004

Comment: I'm assuming you're going to iterate over the result set. Can't you just iterate in reverse order?

Comment: @xmas79 You are correct in case of iteration (e.g. when creating a JSON response) I can loop from end to start. It is simple and gives the required result. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the ORDER BY clause

```
select * from data1 where asset_id = 8 ORDER BY date asc limit 1000;
```

More information available here: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useColumnsSort.html

Comment: This will return oldest 1000 row in asc order, but Shay want to get 1000 recent row in asc order

Comment: Good call, I misread what she was trying to accomplish.  In that case the answer is No.

Comment: Yes, I need the last entered 1000 rows.